# Cannot turn on Airflow's Smart Sensors feature (custom sensor)

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to use Airflow's [Smart Sensors feature](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/smart-sensors.html) on a custom sensor operator (i.e. subclass of `BaseSensorOperator`). The documentation on this feature is pretty sparse right now.

The shard jobs (`smart_sensor_group_shard_[x]`) are running, but I don't think they are picking up my sensors. Those logs say `Loaded 0 sensor_works`.

**I think the problem is that `BaseSensorOperator.is_smart_sensor_compatible()` is returning False even though I have turned the feature on in my configuration**. Here is my configuration:

```
[smart_sensor]
sensors_enabled = MyCustomSensor
use_smart_sensor = True
```

But here are logs from `MySensorOperator`:

```
INFO - self.sensor_service_enabled=False
INFO - self.sensors_support_sensor_service={'NamedHivePartitionSensor'}
INFO - Sensor is NOT Smart Sensor compatible
```

As you can see, the operator still sees Airflow's default settings for those configuration values. I don't know why this inconsistency happens, because I can see the configuration set properly in the UI.

### The rest of my code

Relevant code from MyCustomSensor:

```
class MyCustomSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    poke_context_fields = ['some_arg', 'use_smart_sensor']

    def __init__(self, some_arg,
                 use_smart_sensor=False,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        self.some_arg = some_arg
        self.use_smart_sensor = use_smart_sensor
        super(MyCustomSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def is_smart_sensor_compatible(self):

        # If we have turned it off.
        if not self.use_smart_sensor:
            is_compatible = False
        else:
            self.soft_fail = False

            # super() should be BaseSensorOperator
            is_compatible = super().is_smart_sensor_compatible()

        log.info(f'{self.sensor_service_enabled=}')
        log.info(f'{self.sensors_support_sensor_service=}')

        if is_compatible:
            log.info('Sensor IS Smart Sensor compatible')
        else:
            log.info('Sensor is NOT Smart Sensor compatible')
        return is_compatible
```

How I create my sensor task:

```
# NOTE: I think that poke_interval may
#   be ignored when we are using Smart 
#   Sensors.
my_sensor = MyCustomSensor(
    task_id='some_name',
    prior_task='some_other_name',
    timeout=518400,
    mode='reschedule',
    poke_interval=30,
    use_smart_sensor=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

I am using Cloud Composer, specifically version `composer-1.17.1-airflow-2.1.2`. I have verified that these are not blocked configurations for Cloud Composer.

Comment: I believe you should use `reschedule` mode not poke to get it working. - I think you should also log the "is_smart_sensor_compatible()" result to see if it works as expected

Comment: @JarekPotiuk I tried changing mode to `reschedule` as suggested but it didn't help. I've also added logging. But I think I have narrowed down the problem, it is that `BaseSensorOperator.is_smart_sensor_compatible()` does not see the Smart Sensors configuration. I have rewritten my question to reflect this new information. Thanks for any other ideas you may have.

Comment: For anybody who finds this later: As I mentioned in an edit to the accepted answer, the [Deferrable Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/deferring.html) feature is now preferred over Smart Sensors beginning in Airflow 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error using your code and when I updated the values of `sensors_enabled` and `use_smart_sensor` using command `gcloud composer environments update` on my existing Cloud Composer instance. It seems that Cloud Composer did not apply the new configuration on run time.

But I was able to find a workaround for this. See steps below:

1. I created a new composer instance and at the creation page I already defined Airflow config overrides.

> [image]

2. Using your DAG, I ran a test and the Airflow configuration were applied correctly.

[image]

I created a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/201618369) to report this to the Cloud Composer engineering team.

**UPDATE:**

Another workaround is to set a dummy environment variable to force the workers to restart and apply the changes on Airflow configs.

```
gcloud composer environments update <composer_env_name> \
--location <location> \
--update-env-variables=DUMMY=dummy
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Beginning with Airflow 2.2, [Deferrable Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/deferring.html) are preferred as a solution over Smart Sensors. You should look at that feature first.